# Evaluate $\int_1^\infty\mathrm{e}^{-ax}\log^2\left(x\right)dx$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

So I have to evaluate the following integral, with a hint of substituting $\log x$ with $t$ (and knowing that $a>1$):
$$\int_1^\infty\mathrm{e}^{-ax}\log^2\left(x\right)dx$$

If I'm not mistaken that would give us $\int_0^\infty\mathrm{e}^{-ae^t+t}t^2dt$, but I have no idea how it is of any use.

Comment: Hmm, you can get through one step of integration by parts, lettting $u=t^2$ and $$dv=e^te^{-ae^t}\,dt =-\frac{1}{a}d\left(e^{-ae^t}\right).$$ But after that, I’m not sure.

Comment: Maple says $${\frac {1/6\,{\pi}^{2}+{\gamma}^{2}+2\,\ln  \left( a \right) \gamma+
 \left( \ln  \left( a \right)  \right) ^{2}}{a}}-2\,
{\mbox{$_3$F$_3$}(1,1,1;\,2,2,2;\,-a)}$$

Comment: @GEdgar. Another expression  $$2\,\, G_{2,3}^{3,0}\left(a\left|
\begin{array}{c}
 0,0 \\
 -1,-1,-1
\end{array}
\right.\right)$$